# write a I2C code for sending data(like sending string or sensor data) from pic microcontroller to arduino?

Tags: pic, i2c, mplab

Write the code using MPLABX IDE ( Can just write the main c code) as i am not understanding the syntax to be used while writing and available functions

Comment: And what you did and tried so far?

Comment: i have tried different basic codes like blink, mapping values of pot to leds brightness on mplabx with pic i2d

Comment: about i2c i am trying to do it with mcc but i am having problems with reading and writing data in programming i am searching on how to use the generated functions as there is no any example or description on them

Comment: please please can you help if you know i am trying my best :(